# Symfony2 and PHP affected by DST, how do I stop this from affecting me?

Tags: php, sql-server, date, symfony, dst

In my Symfony 2 project we need to store a variety of information using dates and times. Currently in the database we are storing all of that information using `date` for the column type. And everything goes well when the information is stored for the first time in the database.

The issue is that, when I use the same form type for modifying the information, the data is altered after issuing a `merge` using Doctrine. Worse is, the database information, if I modify it without a frontend (using a `UPDATE` command), is stored without any issues, and it's displayed as it should be.

I have researched a bit on this issue, and it's because Symfony takes the server's timezone and applies it to the input data during the transformation from view to model. PHP usually considers DSTs, but because of political issues PHP is not taking the correct DST end date (it should have ended in March but it ended in April, and PHP takes the original March date) and thus the data gets altered correspondingly.

What should I do to avoid this problem from happening any further? In my country, DSTs have been somewhat variable in the last few years and I cannot trust my computer to take the correct date. I would like to make it timezone-agnostic.

- How should I store my dates in the database?
- How should I manage my dates in the Symfony project?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: I think you can find multi options to set or define a default time zone in you Symfony app [http://www.epicfoobar.com/2013/10/how-to-set-time-zone-in-symfony2/]

Comment: The issue is that my time zone considers DSTs. The DSTs it considers are in dates the government changes at will, and we do not know when or if they will change the time. PHP has no way to know that, and as such the system is prone to errors. I have already set the time zone in php.ini because it should be immutable, but the DST throws that away and it's useless if I try to redeclare it somewhere else because the results will basically be the same.

Comment: In this case what do you think about having an application settings in your application so that you(admin user) be able to choose the valid timezone for the app, base on the government decision?

Comment: That's a good idea, but I found another solution and already tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have an immutable PHP timezone, always resort to UTC by doing this in php.ini:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Module Settings ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

...

[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone=UTC
```

This will force PHP to have a timezone that will never change despite any DST changes.